Identify: dice results buy cards that give powerups to dice results
I am trying to remember the name of a game...
It is a game that basically only has cards (more squarish than usual, if I recall correctly) and dice. The dice are standard 6 sided dice, not custom.
All cards lie on the table from the start, and you buy them with dice rolls. All the cards are known and shown in the table from the beginning of the game (I don't know if there is a setup to choose the cards)
You use the dice to buy cards, and the cards give you powers relating to the dice
So, for example, a card might add or remove one from a dice
And the cards cost specific dice rolls.
One card can be bought with 2 even dice, another, with 2 4 and 6, and another requires a straight (IDK if those specific examples are in the game)
I think the theme was some sort of noble court. It was a competitive game, and I remember playing with at least 3 people

Can you remember anything about the theme?  Was it in a dungeon, space, monsters fighting in New York/Tokyo?  Was it a single player game, or were there multiple people?  Were you competing against each other, or working together?

I think the theme was some sort of noble court. It was a competitive game, and I remember playing with at least 3 people

The answer is To Court the King.
Thanks to David Robie's answer, I found the answer using board game geek's
advanced search. In BGG: advance-search, I selected:

max year 2017
3+ players
medieval
dice
dice rolling
removed cooperative game
de-selected expansions



It may be Knights.

Capturing castles with die rolling.  There appear to be no components other than dice and cards.
Found on BGG with:
Category: + Card Game, + Dice, + Medieval

Mechanic: - Cooperative Game, + Dice Rolling


unfortunately, no, that is not it, but thanks!
